# how to download an image from uploads folder which is placed where the following program is saved,php

Tags: php, html, sql

I have saved an image which is in upload folder, the link is saved in sql table,    how should i write a program to download the images from that folder?

Comment: Can you explain to better? It's not so clear your question.

Comment: I want to fetch the link from the table and download the file from that link. i have more than 10 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for database connection try these codes..

**database.php**

```
   <?php
try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', "username" , "password");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch(PDOException $e){
    print "error in connection" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

now,this php file will access the name of image file stored in database
**image.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require_once 'database.php';

    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT image_name FROM tablename");
    $row = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $filename = $value['image_name'];



        ?>
        <a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $filename;?>"><?php echo $filename . "<br>";?></a>
        <?php }?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**download.php**

```
    <?php 

$filename = $_GET["id"];
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
readfile ($filename);

exit;
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchall() on a non-object in G:\x\htdocs\download photo\index.php on line 11

Comment: can u please say how to fetch if i have 2 image names stored in one column like this 
"uploads/25-08-2015-1440485906-20131115_134926.jpg","uploads/25-08-2015-1440485906-20131115_134926.jpg" and make the image download @itz raghu

Comment: drop your all file alog with database at dropbox..i will help you!